# Is there is an alternative to Color.argb for API Level < 26?

Tags: java, android, xml, colors

i'm currently developing an application with API level 16. I wanted to use Color.argb() but it don't work for API Level < 26.

Is there any library or something similar that could work with any API Level > 21 ?

Here is the part of the function I use :

```
private void checkInputs()
{
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText()))
{
signUpBtn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
}
else
{
signUpBtn.setEnabled(false);
signUpBtn.setTextColor(Color.argb(50F, 255, 255, 255));
}
}
```

Comment: @PrinceAli i have gone through this link but it dosen't work.

Comment: @lucy: that will work. If it doesn't for you, then you need to be more specific than "dosen't work".

Comment: @JoachimSauer can you guide me how to resolve my error using this link?

Comment: lucy: don't use `50F` as that's a floating point value. Use `50` instead.